# Lost follower after deleting skyrim dlc

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3, skyrim-dragonborn

Okay so, my story's a bit confusing and I've been trying for five days to fix my problem so I figured I would ask here.

I had both dlcs for skyrim downloaded on PS3. Then one day I go to load my game and after the load screen (with the spinning things and info about the game) it just went black. I looked up how to fix it and it said delete the dlcs then reinstall them. So I did.

I was stupid enough to open the game (which I was in skaal village at the save) when the dlc was  downloading and not installed. I wound up in riverwood and my follower (Calder) was no where to be found. After I reinstalled dragon born I went back to skaal village but he wasn't there. I tried waiting in  solsthiem and in skyrim in case he was just catching up to me but that didn't work. I also tried the "go to jail" trick many times too (I got a 45 bounty for punching a chicken)

I tried getting a new follower but they all say I still have one so I can't get a hardy pack mule for all my quests. I have no idea what to do and it's just annoying me at this point.

Answer (score 2):

You can try and force a companion change. I believe that one of the following quests will leave you with an empty companion slot after being completed.

[image: -this table from the Skyrim wiki]
[Link for more follower info.](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers#Quest_Followers)

After completing a quest from the ones above try and wait a week or two of in-game time and than go to the place where you would normally hire them. In your case go to Windhelmand search for Calder.

There is the possibility that having loaded a safe that was and playing without installing the DLC might have deleted your followers inventory.

If this doesn't work I believe that loading an old safe will do but if you lack one there is always the possibility to try and port your current safe to PC and using console bring back Calder.Keep in mind that this is not easy.

Comment: Unfortunately I have done all these quests!

Answer (score 1):

I have some solutions that might help, please be sure to let me know if they don't.

- First go to any city with a king like whiterun for example. Ask the king to buy a house, sometimes is usually the servant next to him. Once you buy the house, sleep in the bed for three days. Your lost follower should be there or leve by that time. (This worked for me).
- You're going to go to this custom location right south of Solitude. When you are in the path wait for a straight dog to come by, his name is Meeko. He's going to run to his shack all you have to do is follow him.

[image: Custom Location south of Solitude.]

Once you are in the shack with Meeko, all you have to do is to talk to Meeko and ask him to follow you, he will get rid of any lost follower that you have. Hope this helped.

Comment: I'll try that last one! I tried the sleeping for three days already and it hasn't done anything. I was looking for a quest that has a person replace your follower automatically but I've done most quests. I'll let you know if this works!

Comment: It didn't work, it's probably because you're allowed an animal follower along with your human follower.